# Kosher birds in the Torah

Tags: kashrut-kosher, non-kosher-species, birds

Why is it that the Torah only mentions the non-kosher birds (24 of them), but doesnt mention their simanim, While by the kosher animals the Torah does mention simanim and which specific animals are kosher? Why leave out the simonim for birds altogether?

Comment: Why do you think there are Simanim for birds? It could be there are no physical traits that identity them and only them. It seems highly unlikely that there exists certain physical traits that exist in all birds but these 24 species.

Comment: what do you mean the Talmud in Chullin 65 describes them,not following.

Comment: Are those traits just sufficient or also necessary? (In any event, information that motivates your question should always be [edit]ed into the question itself.)

Comment: the pashut pshat is that if we lose the mesorah of a specific bird and we find that it contains all or some(big discussion) of the simanim then its kosher without mesorah (pre Achronim )

Comment: Yes, but is that process guaranteed to not declare some fundamentally kosher birds unkosher (ie is it more machmir than needed)?

Comment: not according to the Rambam

Comment: As @DoubleAA said, "information that motivates your question should always be edited into the question itself." If you have info that makes your question make more sense (e.g. that _simanim_ for birds exist in fact and even that the _Rambam_ holds they're precisely indicative), please [edit] it in, ideally also including how you know.